# Impossible to resolve System.ComponentModel.Component (the dll is referred)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, system.componentmodel

i start telling you that my problem could come from the fact i'm very new in .NET programming and for this reason i cant find a similar answer beacause i dont know what to find. I tryed but nothing.

I'm trying to do a WebService client (with a windows web app) from a wsdl description.
This client requires a reference to the assembly System.Web.Services.dll
This dll have a reference to System.ComponentModel.Component. The error in compiling is:(i translated from italian):

Impossible to resolve the class or the interface System.ComponentModel.Component in the assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referred by System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.

I checked. The dll System.ComponentModel is automatically referred by this kind of project.
The stange fact is that if i try to do a simple console program with a main, the error will come in any case but it does not stop the application and i'm able to run the application correctly.

How to solve the problem? Could the dll be corrupted?

UPDATE: I found that this could be a problem regarding security and protection issues but i cant solve it. Maybe this post can help you more then me http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1131887

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly the same as your problem, but the symptoms and error you get are suspiciously similar to that described in [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015129)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the solution you posted but it didn't solve the problem (i dont have the file config where it would be the problem).